# C++ To C# mouse_event

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to figure out how to do

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, pixels_x, 0, 0, 0);
```

in C#, I have found the way to do it with Cursor but it doesn't work like mouse_event in C++.

Comment: C# can call `mouse_event` directly if you really need to, but first what are you trying to do in C# that calling `mouse_event` [is the solution to that problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Perhaps we can help you solve that instead.

Comment: I need it to be called on a timer currently.

Comment: You did not answer my question, you answered **HOW** you are using mouse_event. **WHY** are you calling mouse_event (in a timer or otherwise)? Explain the problem that using mouse event solves. Also update your question explaining what about Cursor did not meet your needs.

Comment: Well, I am converting some code that's in C++ to C#. The math, the variables and everything are the same. However when execute Cursor and now mouse_event(Found out how to do it in C#) it moves it more then it should do.

Comment: http://mobile.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_graphics/mouse/article.php/c6133/Detecting-Mouse-Button-Events-in-C.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);
```

the above will allow you to call mouse_event from C#, pass the same numeric values you're using in C++ and you should be covered